# Scala Play External Redirect

Tags: scala, redirect, playframework

As I'm working on implementing TinyUrl, I want to redirect users to a webpage based on the input hash.

```
  def getTask(hash: Int) = Action {
    val url: Option[String] = Task.getTask(hash)
    // redirect to show(url) 
  }
```

However, I don't know how to redirect the user to an external URL.

I saw this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019420/play-framework-redirect-with-params), but I encountered this compile-time error when I used `redirect`

`not found: value redirect`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`redirect` doesn't exist.
But `Redirect`, which is a member of the `play.api.mvc` package, does.

Here's an example of what your action should look like:

```
import play.api.mvc._

def getTask(hash: Int) = Action {
  val url: Option[String] = Task.getTask(hash)

  url match {
    case Some(url) => Redirect(url)
    case None => NotFound("This URL leads nowhere. :(")
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try that, the redirect goes to `http://localhost:9000/tasks/www.google.com` and the following "Bad Request" error shows up: `For request 'GET /tasks/www.google.com' [Cannot parse parameter hash as Int: For input string: "www.google.com"]`