# Play Framework sending POST request data to GET

Tags: scala, playframework, httprequest, playframework-2.1

How would I send request data from a POST request to a GET request using Scala Play?(Using Play Framework 2.1.1)

My goal is to have a single page "Reports" that works like this: The report is a GET request, so if needed you could bookmark this report. The report consists of a table of models, and each model row has a delete button at the end. I want to click the delete button, have it post the id to my controller then reload the page with the reports filter parameters still on.

Currently I have the delete button just adding to the get, which works correctly but the remove=id parameter stays in the request/address bar. Therefore it tries to delete this model every time the page is reloaded. What I would like to do is have this form POST and then remove the model, then send all the request parameters other than remove to a GET request.

I would rather do this without javascript/AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You could reconstruct a URL through using queryString and path from the request object. Then redirect that back (without the delete parameter) 
[How to get query string parameters in java play framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907996/how-to-get-query-string-parameters-in-java-play-framework)

Or if you have the call setup in the routes file to parse out, use the reverse route minus the delete parameter.
[Play Framework - Redirect with params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019420/play-framework-redirect-with-params)
http://www.mariussoutier.com/blog/2012/12/10/playframework-routes-part-1-basics/

```
  def index() = Action { request =>
    import play.api.Play.current
    println(request.queryString)
    val allWithoutDel = request.queryString - "del"   //del is the query parameter
    println(allWithoutDel)
    val url = request.path + // fold or map the allWithoutDel down to a URL string again
    redirect(url)
    }
```

Comment: That's what I tried originally. But `request.queryString` is empty. The parameters are there if I print out the `request.body` though.